# Excel Offset Subtraction Inside Cells?

Tags: excel

I have thousands of rows of these two columns worth of data that looks exactly to this. The date and time of an event is listed inside a single cell. I need to be able to subtract the time in one cell from the other, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this.

For instance, I would need to somehow pull 4:00am and subtract the difference of 6:00am - leaving me an answer of 2 hours. Thank you ahead of time!

```
Nov 25, 2016 4:00:00 AM  Nov 25, 2016 6:00:00 AM
Nov 25, 2016 4:00:00 AM  Nov 25, 2016 6:00:00 AM
Nov 25, 2016 4:00:00 AM  Nov 25, 2016 5:15:00 AM
Nov 25, 2016 4:00:00 AM  Nov 25, 2016 6:00:00 AM
Nov 25, 2016 4:00:00 AM  Nov 25, 2016 6:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

In C1:

```
=24*(B1-A1)
```

and fill down.

Dates in Excel are managed such that subtracting A1 from B1 gives a fraction of a day, so multiply by 24 to get number of hours.